# How to convert List in c# to array in javascript .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var imgs = @Model.EditProductImageList.ToArray();
    console.log(imgs); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following you can serialize your object into a json and this can be parsed into an array with javascript

So your in your page/view would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = '@Json.Serialize(Model.EditProductImageList)';
    var array = JSON.parse(json);
</script>
```